# Why does a Swift enum with optional associated value require trailing parentheses when being declared?

Tags: swift, enums

I have a Swift Enum with a computed property. There are several cases that include a single, optional, associated value. If I want to call the computed property on a variable holding a case value that contains an associated value, then I have to declare the variable with trailing parentheses, otherwise I get a compiler error.

If I don't want to call the computed property, then I don't need to include the parentheses.

Why is that and how are the trailing parentheses changing the "type" of the property such that a computed property can then be called on it?

A simple example to highlight the issue:

```
import Foundation

enum Animal {
  case dog
  case other(String? = nil)

  var isFriendly:Bool {
    switch self {
      case .dog: return true
      default:   return false
    }
  }
}

// This generates the error:
// Value of type '(String?) -> Animal' has no member 'isFriendly'

let exoticBird = Animal.other
print("Is exotic bird friendly: \(exoticBird.isFriendly)")

// This line, with the trailing parentheses, does not. 

let exoticFish = Animal.other()
print("Is exotic fish friendly: \(exoticFish.isFriendly)")
```

Comment: Your code gives a compile error: `Default arguments are not allowed in enum cases`

Comment: @ielyamani: It compiles with Xcode 11 beta.

Comment: @MartinR Just checked, yes. Here is a relevant thread https://forums.swift.org/t/default-values-for-enum-associated-values/3437

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It compiles with Xcode 11 beta and produces a case constructor. [Here](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0155-normalize-enum-case-representation.md) is the link to Swift evolution proposal.

Your `exoticBird` is not `Animal`, it is rather a case constructor. `Alt + Click` on your `exoticBird` variable and you will see type of it defined as follows.

```
let exoticBird: (String?) -> Animal
```

I think when you leave out associated type in enum, it creates a function based on associated type.

You could pass string to it and then call `isFriendly` on it like so,

```
isExoticBird(nil).isFriendly
```

So, it seems that you cannot leave associated type if you want to create the type explicitly unless you want to do some functional programming.

**Now, Small functional transformation with the case constructor type.**

Define a function like so,

```
func isOtherAnimalFriendly(_ f: @escaping (String?) -> Animal) -> (String?) -> Bool {
    return { animalName in
        f(animalName).isFriendly
    }
}
```

And now, use the following code,

```
let exoticFish = Animal.other
let namedAnimal = isOtherAnimalFriendly(exoticFish)
```

Notice that the type of namedAnimal is now,

```
let namedAnimal: (String?) -> Bool
```

And you could use this new function with name,

```
print("Is exotic fish friendly: \(namedAnimal(nil))")
```

Also use higher order functions such as map on it,

```
["Cat", "Cow", "Horse"].map(Animal.other) // array of animals with associated values
```

Comment: That function is called the “case constructor,” compare https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0155-normalize-enum-case-representation.md

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for linking evolution. Seems interesting.

Comment: Thanks Sandeep. Not sure I entirely follow the additional functional stuff, but it sounds like `Animal.other` and `Animal.other()` return two different types, yet both are considered to be an `Animal` when it comes to passing parameters around both can be used in a `switch` statement as intended. I can live with the trailing parentheses but was curious why that was the case. (I stand correct as I can't use `Animal.other` as I expected because of its type. Must have tested the wrong code. The trailing parenthesis are absolutely required.)

Comment: I meant that Animal.other simply creates a function with a type of (String?) -> Animal. So, you could pass this to map, or compose with some other functions. See my last example using map.